# Custom Textinput shows border around itself in IOS - React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I've created a custom text input component for my react native app. It has no issues in the android build. But In IOS, the custom component draws a border around its view.

[image]

This is how it looks in ios. You can see a border around it.

I want it took to look like this in IOS without a square border

[image]

This is my custom component (MyInput.js)

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Text,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
const {View, TextInput, StyleSheet} = require('react-native');

const MyInput = (props) => {
  const [hide, makeHide] = useState(false);
  const [phAanimatedValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [labelAanimatedValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [overflow, setOverflow] = useState('hidden');

  const movePlaceHolderLeft = phAanimatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -10],
  });

  const moveLabelRight = labelAanimatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-10, 0],
  });

  const animatePlaceHolder = (v, hide) => {
    Animated.timing(phAanimatedValue, {
      toValue: v,
      duration: 50,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(() => {
      makeHide(hide);
      animateLabel(v);
    });
  };

  const animateLabel = (v) => {
    setOverflow('visible');
    Animated.timing(labelAanimatedValue, {
      toValue: v,
      duration: 50,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.input,
        {
          overflow: overflow,
          borderColor:props.error?"#ff0033":"#e5deda",

        },
      ]}>
      <TextInput
        onFocus={() => {
          animatePlaceHolder(1, true);
        }}
        ref={props.cref}
        value={props.value}
        onChangeText={(v) => props.onChangeText(v)}
        style={{paddingStart: 25}}
        onBlur={() => {
          if (props.value.length > 0) {
            makeHide(true);
          } else {
            animatePlaceHolder(0, false);
          }
        }}
      />
      {!hide ? (
        <Animated.Text
          onPress={() => props.cref.current.focus()}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: [{translateX: movePlaceHolderLeft}],
            height: '100%',
            fontFamily: 'Muli-Regular',
            width: '100%',
            marginStart: 20,
            paddingVertical:15,
            color: props.error ? '#ff0033' : '#a6a6a6',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
          }}>
          {props.label}
        </Animated.Text>
      ) : (
        <Animated.Text
          onPress={() => props.cref.current.focus()}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: [{translateX: moveLabelRight}],
            marginTop: -10,
            zIndex:1000,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color:props.error?'red':'#e5deda',
            marginStart: 20,
            fontFamily: 'Muli-Regular',
            paddingHorizontal: 5,
            textAlignVertical: 'top',
          }}>
          {props.label}
        </Animated.Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#e5deda',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#353839',
    paddingVertical:15,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    lineHeight: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Muli-Regular',
    fontWeight: '600',
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
});

export default MyInput;
```

This is How I Render:

```
<MyInput
          value={value}
          onChangeText={(v)=>
          {
          setValue(v)
          setError(true)
          }}
          cref={postalRef}
          error={error}
          label="Postal Code"
        />
```

Is there any solution for this or is this a bug?

Comment: Can someone check whether this issue comes in your simulator/iPhone and why is this coming only in ios devices not android?

Comment: Fixed by removing overflow and worked good in ios. huh, buggy React native.